# What replaces the old HTMLElement.style when using the new Fable.Browser.Dom

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I started a project with fulma-demo and tried transplanting some code from another sample project which used an older version of Fable and Fulma. It has the following line which will not compile:

```
testWrapper.style.borderColor <- "#E95D0F"
```

Evidently the **style** property no longer exists on HTMLElement. What replaces it?

Edit:

```
open Fable.Core.JsInterop
open Browser
open Browser.Types
let testWrapper = document.querySelector(".test-wrapper")  :?> HTMLElement
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with the release of Fable.Core v3, Alfonso started to rework several "historical" packages like `Fable.Import.Browser`.

> It's possible you haven't noticed but many Fable libraries have a dependency to the monstrous `Fable.Import.Browser` package, a single file of more than 12000 lines that most IDEs struggled to open. This file was automatically generated in its origin using ts2fable from Typescript definitions. It also contained manual tweaks however, and this together with its size made it very difficult to update.

Quotes from [Fable blog](https://fable.io/blog/Announcing-2-2.html)

So `Fable.Import.Browser` has been splitted in several packages:

- Fable.Browser.Blob
- Fable.Browser.Dom
- Fable.Browser.Event
- Fable.Browser.Performance
- Fable.Browser.Url
- Fable.Browser.WebSocket
- Fable.Browser.WebStorage
- Fable.Browser.XMLHttpRequest

However, it is still missing `Fable.Browser.Svg` and `Fable.Browser.Css`. I already have a version for `Fable.Browser.Svg` and I am working on making a version of `Fable.Browser.Css` so hopefully they will soon be available to use.

That said, if you need to access the `style` property of an element right now, you will need to use `dynamic typing`:

```
open Fable.Core.JsInterop
open Browser
open Browser.Types

let testWrapper = document.querySelector(".test-wrapper")  :?> HTMLElement

testWrapper?style?borderColor <- "#E95D0F"
```

Comment: I had read that post but for some reason did not register the comment about the missing Fable.Browser.Css

Comment: Wonder what is left "todo". https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-browser/blob/8498cbb1e48c64da1a7703b089475877f4c4ff74/src/Dom/Browser.Dom.fs#L1314-L1315

Comment: The TODO you commented about can be removed because it is now included in Fable.Browser.Css 

https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-browser/blob/1807005f6f172028543c78cba852ca06997924e6/src/Css/Browser.Css.Ext.fs#L20-L22

It is just something we forgot to remove